# How to start activity if textview is empty?

Tags: java, android

In the below given code, I have basically used `get()` method and displayed the data in `TextView`, and I want to start another activity if the `TextView` is empty, I have tried many options but it just won't work.

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(url)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build();

Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
params.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
SharedPreferences p = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("secret", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
String token = p.getString("token", "");
params.put("Authorization", "Token " + token);


PlaceHolderApi placeHolderApi = retrofit.create(PlaceHolderApi.class);
        Call<List<profileDetails>> call=placeHolderApi.getDetails(params);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<profileDetails>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<profileDetails>> call, Response<List<profileDetails>> response) {
                List<profileDetails> data=response.body();
                for (int i=0; i<data.size();i++){
                    name.append(""+data.get(i).getFullname());

                    age.append(""+data.get(i).getAge());

                    address.append("Address: "+data.get(i).getLocation());

                    gender.append("Gender: "+data.get(i).getGender());

                    num.append("Number: "+data.get(i).getPhone_number());

                    uId.append("Id: "+data.get(i).getId());

                    RoomId = Integer.parseInt(data.get(i).getId());}

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<profileDetails>> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e("kk","lal"+t);
                Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error Cause : "+t,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: "I have tried many options" - show what you have tried and describe what happened when it didn't work (in the question, not on the comments).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it is not clear what you have already tried but let me give you a simple solution you can just check by

```
you_textview.setText("your text from server")

if(your_textview.getText().toString().isEmpty())
{
  startActivity(new Intent(this,MainActivity.class));  
}
```